# use the total data or separate it into correlation matrix?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

I have a dataset where with doses of a product that will interact with a nozzle and form a spray of specific drops. And from these drops, I have several variables that I would like to correlate with the physicochemical characteristics of the product tested (all variables are quantitative). Is the best option to correlate by separating the matrices by the dose of the product? (perhaps see the effect of the dose in the correlation?). Or run all together and I get more confidence in the correlation?

Example: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-matrix-a-quick-start-guide-to-analyze-format-and-visualize-a-correlation-matrix-using-r-software

Comment: Your description is a little too vague and confusing to suggest good advice.  Could you perhaps illustrate your dataset by showing a few representative lines?  What do you mean by "matrices" and how are they related to your dataset?  What do you mean by "own" doses?